# Parent div has no dimensions

Tags: html, css

Currently my parent div is showing up as a dimensionless div (0 by 0 px). I am trying to have a flexible parent div thats size is not explicitly mentioned but rather adaps to the size of its content. Here is what I have so far thats producing a 0px by 0px parent. Hope someone can give me a solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnailDeal">
    <div class="thumbnailImage">
        <div class="thumbnailDescription">
            <span class="thumbnailTitle">3 Maki Orders</span> 
            <div class="thumbnailPrices"><span class="thumbnailOriginal">$25</span>&nbsp;$<span class="thumbnailActual">15</span></div>

            <br>
            <span class="thumbnailRestaurant">New Generation Sushi</span><br>
            <span class="thumbnailLocation">11 St Joseph st.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thumbnailDeal">
    <div class="thumbnailImage">
        <div class="thumbnailDescription">
            <span class="thumbnailTitle">3 Maki Orders</span> 
            <div class="thumbnailPrices"><span class="thumbnailOriginal">$25</span>&nbsp;$<span class="thumbnailActual">15</span></div>

            <br>
            <span class="thumbnailRestaurant">New Generation Sushi</span><br>
            <span class="thumbnailLocation">11 St Joseph st.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnailDeal{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:1%;

}

.thumbnailImage{
    width:360px;
    height:315px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(../assets/5.jpeg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position:absolute;
}

.thumbnailDescription{

    height:28%;
    width:100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    padding:10px;
}

.thumbnailTitle{
    color:white;
    font-size:17px;
}

.thumbnailRestaurant{
    color:#FD8B2B;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

.thumbnailLocation{
    color:#9E9E97;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    padding-left:10px;

}

.thumbnailPrices{
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:-13px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumbnailOriginal{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color:#9E9E97

}
.thumbnailActual{
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute` elements get out of the flow and the parent won't have height/width from his childs anymore.

You have to find another way to position your elements if you want to have a proper height/width to the parent :)

Comment: THank you so much! Straightforward simple answer :D

Comment: You have to think different: Put your parent with a `position:relative` that will help absolute child to be relative to his parent. Then you can set a width/height to the parent and ask the childs to have a `width:100%` and `height:100%` I think you could take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/position